# Android Google Maps [React Native?] "API key not found. Check that.." Error

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

Hi I am new to react native. I just made a new application. When I don't have a map component in my application and my other components work fine. However when I add this in my `render(){return(..`

```
  <MapView
    ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }}
    mapType={MAP_TYPES.TERRAIN}
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={this.state.region}
    onRegionChange={region => this.onRegionChange(region)}
  />
```

I get the error:

[image]

I did a search of the project folder to find a AndroidMainfest.xml and I found a couple. I changed the one in: \android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug

from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pickup_sports_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <!-- Include required permissions for Google Maps API to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.pickup_sports_app.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pickup_sports_app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pickup_sports_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <!-- Include required permissions for Google Maps API to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.pickup_sports_app.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pickup_sports_app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC-V3J1Wz4wqgHqrqffIeZqhVM0gDfTsIg" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I even just tried it with only the meta-deta API Key one.

Some other information:
I got the API key from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup.

After I changed it I just saved the file and restarted the simulator restarted the app with react-native run-android in the directory with command prompt. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to "Rebuild" the project.

I am using the Airbnb react-native-maps component that Facebook recommends using: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

I did the `npm install react-native-maps --save` and `react-native link react-native-maps` recently because this is a brand new project (error in the new version they provide or something?). The emulator is android 7.1.1.

Here is the SDK Manager for the android studio simulator:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the correct change of adding the API_KEY element. However, edit the file at location:

```
\android\app\\**src**\main (Source directory)
```

instead of

```
\android\app\\**build**\intermediates\manifests\full\debug (Build directory)
```

Comment: I've added API_KEY at right place in right file, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to delite from manifest this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

This data you can move to build.gradle config in chapter dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
```